# Force DbContext to throw Exception on SaveChanges() in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I´m using EF Core 2.2.0 with an `InMemoryDatabase` for testing. Is there a way to make it throw an exception when an operation is called, such as `SaveChanges` or `Find`?

I want to verify that a my business logic is handling the exception in a particular way. I know that I can abstract the `DbContext` all together, but with EF Core and the `InMemoryDatabase` I wish to access the DbContext directly without any more abstractions.

In my unit test I'm currently creating the `DbContext` as such:

```
var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .Options;
var context = new MyContext(dbOptions));
```

And my logic (extremely simplified):

```
public MyClass
{
    private MyContext _context;

    public MyClass(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {

        try
        {
            */ .. Other stuff .. */
            var entity = context.Find(id);
            entity.SomeProperty = "Foo";
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // I want to test this code...
            Log.Write("Something");
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without using a mocked abstraction, inheritance may be the path.  Create a derived class, override the desired member to throw exception when invoked, update test accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use my EntityFrameworkCoreMock library as a base, see https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock

and then override the behavior of the `SaveChanges` method like this:

```
dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Callback(() => throw new Exception());
```